# C# how to start a new "thread" in an async method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have two async methods, **Test1** and **Test2**.

In **Test1**, I want to call **Test2** "in a new thread".

In other words, I want a separate "thread" to go to execute **Test2**, and **Test1** step over **Test2** call and do not wait for it to finish.

```
private async Task Test2()
{
    // some time-consuming work to do...
}

public async Task Test1()
{
    // How to call Test2 and immediately move on to the next line and let a separate "thread" to
    // execute Test2?
}
```

Comment: `Task.Run(() => Test2())` would run `Test2` on a thread pool thread. I'm not sure it's a great idea to just ignore the `Task` returned by that, however. I suspect you will want to `await` it at some point to know when it's finished / handle any exceptions.

Comment: Test2 never ends. I don't want a new System.Threading.Thread to run Test2, because an explicit thread fails to benefit from async. I want the async mechanism to handle Test2. How do I do it?

Comment: How does using another thread fail to benefit from async? How does that square with your request to have a separate thread execute it (which is what `Task.Run` does)? And how do you mean you 'want the async mechanism to handle' it?

Comment: @CharlesMager I suppose the `Test2` method has some async logic and uses awaits in it. Maybe some `Task.Delay` for recurrent logic, etc. In this case new thread would only run the initial logic before the first await and the all continuations will get scheduled to the ThreadPool anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that `Test2` has some CPU-intensive logic and some asynchronous calls:

```cs
private async Task Test2()
{
    for (var i = 1; i < 1_000_000; i++)
    {
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    for (var i = 1; i < 1_000_000; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

If `Test2` is invoked without `await`, then current thread would execute logic before fist `await` in `Test2` method prior to returning to `Test1`. Meaning execution will return to `Test1` only after the first `for` loop finishes:

```cs
public async Task Test1()
{
    var _ = Test2();
}
```

If you require `Test1` to continue execution immediately after the `Test2` invocation, than it has to be scheduled to another thread from `ThreadPool`, which can be done with `Task.Run`, for example:

```cs
public async Task Test1()
{
    var _ = Task.Run(() => Test2());
}
```

In this case you don't have the control when `Test2` actually gets executed by `ThreadPool` (it can happen that `Test1` exits even before `Test2` is started) and the task, returned by `Task.Run` will complete only when `Task2` exits or throws an error. So you can `await` it or use the task later in your code, or simply ignore it, if your logic is not concerned about the result.

And if you are not going to await the task from `Test2` method, it's worthwhile to catch and handle/log possible errors in it directly, otherwise it will fail silently, which might cause hard to investigate issues.

Comment: I got your comment, and agree, I like the explanation in your answer.